# How to fix memory corruption?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm getting some odd, unexplained errors and crashes in my program. I've been stepping through debugging and looking around, and I noticed that I'm setting a variable to NULL, but if I set a breakpoint immediately after, the variable is set to `0xcdcdcd00` even though I just set it to NULL.

It looks like there is some sort of memory corruption happening in my program.

What are some good techniques for finding the cause of the memory corruption? I added a large chunk of code before this started happening, so while going through my code, what are something I should be looking for that can cause memory corruption?

I have a class called `monster`, derived from a class called `mob`

I execute the following code:

`monster* newMon = new monster();`

which calls the constructor on monster class:

```
monster::monster() : mob() {
    this->renderer = NULL;
}
```

when I break at the end of this function, renderer = `0xcdcdcd00` or sometimes `0xcdcdcdcd`

Comment: Try including relevant pieces of code in the question.

Comment: You should watch out for pointers and their usage. Using a pointer without allocating it any memory can be a very simple case. Overflowing the memory allocated via malloc/ new should be looked for next.

Comment: In addition using simple C array may cause overflow like int x[5]; x[6]= 10; Start with valgrind and cppcheck.

Comment: should never happen. try to rebuild your app.

Comment: If you execute that code in isolation, it should run without problems. Your error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Are you debugging in 'release'? Try the same compiling with `-O0` set.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. This kind of thing is a common problem that people experience. We should allow people a little time to improve their question when the questioner is actively responding to comments and questsions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
monster::monster() : mob() {
    this->renderer = NULL;
}
```

sets `renderer` to NULL. I'd change it to

```
monster::monster() : mob(), renderer(NULL) {
}
```

but that shouldn't make a difference (other than readability).

The problems is one of two things:

- out of date build
- running with optimizations and checking the value in the debugger (this is my guess). It might tell you that `renderer` is not NULL, but you shouldn't trust the debugger in a release build.

I'm sure that if you output some debug statements, you'll see that the value is actually set correctly:

```
monster::monster() : mob(), renderer(NULL) {
   if (renderer)
       std::cout << "WTH!";
   else
       std::cout << "correctly set to NULL";
}
```

Comment: I tried using a check to see if it's actually NULL, and it seemed to work. However when I set renderer = new monsterRenderer(), render still is equal to 0xcdcdcd00.

Comment: @Brad so? `new` returns a pointer to the newly created object. I don't see the problem...

Comment: the new object should not be located at 0xcdcdcd00.

Comment: @Brad also, how do you know that's the address? Are you checking the address in the debugger? (doing exactly what I said you shouldn't do)

Comment: yeah I was using a breakpoint just after the assignment to check the value. I've always used this method as long as I have been programming and its always worked for me. I've found the solution and have posted it below

Answer (score 1):

You should get yourself a good static code checker such as gimpel lint (which detects a lot of this sort of stuff), and also use valgrind (which is free) or purify or some other runtime checker.

However, if you set a location to zero and immediately after that, the debugger says it's not zero, you may want to make sure you have optimisations switched off. even slightly optimised code can confuse the debugger to near uselessness.

Another question that arises is - is this code multi threaded or is the memory you are inspecting shared with another process? I suspect in this case, you're going to need to examine your code carefully to detect race hazards, and I don't know of any good tools for that.

Comment: The code does have a thread that is handling networking functions, but this hasn't changed before this error occurred. And my program isn't sharing any memory with other processes

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem..

I had the `mob` class defined in two different files. I don't know how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

`0xcdcdcdcd` often indicates that the memory is uninitialised. This can happen if `renderer` is in the base class as well. Try renaming `renderer` to `m_renderer` in class `monster` and see if you get the same problem.